# Router push is not working properly in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

As shown in the code below, there is a code that goes to home when clicked. There is no problem in moving the router-view header when running the server, but if you enter the path directly in the url and click the dashboard function again, the js code animation of the page does not work, but if you press f5 it works. No errors unless you go directly to the URL. I don't know why this error is appearing.

This function only works when you refresh with f5

```html
<script setup>
var scrollEvent = function() {
var scroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollY
var itemList = document.querySelectorAll('.mainsection .section')
Array.prototype.forEach.call(itemList, function(section){
  if(section.offsetTop < scroll) {
    section.classList.remove('animatable')
    section.classList.add('animated')
  }
})
}
<script>
```

dashboard router code

```js
const dashboard = () => {
  router.push({
    path:'/home',
  })
}
```

Comment: Please include some more details in your question. For one, what is calling `dashboard`? Another, you say that "router push" is not working, but then you say that it all works unless you go the the URL directly.

Comment: And, if at all possible, share some sort of reproduction. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) works very well.

Comment: And please, please don't use `var`; use `let` and `const`.